# wxpython + mvc delete controller

Tags: model-view-controller, wxpython

I'm programming in wxpython and I'm trying to use the mvc model. But I'm stuck with a lost controller :) I'll explain.

A have a panel which calls a controller. I do some things. then I destroy my controller and my panel. Well I try.

```
del self.tempMApanel.controller
self.tempMApanel.Destroy()
```

What I know for sure is that the controller isn't linked anymore with the panel because if I 'print' the controller I get an error that says main object has no attribute controller:

```
print "self.tempMApanel.controller: ",self.tempMApanel.controller #'Main' object has no attribute 'controller'
```

At a certain moment I recreate the panel with a new controller. But when I send a message (with pub.Sendmessage) to do something in the controller, the message is picked up by the old controller which isn't connected to a panel and the program complains (ofcourse :) )

SO my specific question is, can you 'kill' a controller and is it possible to have a 'lost', 'single', 'flying' controller?

The past 2 days programming was lifted to another dimension of difficult. All the virtual connections ... sometimes it is difficult to keep track and it is difficult to explain and ask for help. So I hope it is clear what I'm trying to say.

tx in advance and I hope there are some geniuses who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

My day is so good!! I was talking about my 'lost' controller problem with our IT-guy and he said you use a subscriber, maybe your reference to your controller is still in there somewhere. And indeed, the controller was added to a list, so I had to remove the controller from this list and then I could remove my view.

I'm so relieved! The last 3 days there were so many problems in my program and I solved them all but this one. But now I can move on the next part.

So my advice is, always look for references if you see this kind of problem.